# Python Inner Class value assignment

Tags: python, inner-classes

I created a inner class within a class and created two instances of the class, but when assigning different values to the inner class properties, it is assigned to both instances. Can anyone help?
Here's the code

```
class cl1:
    def __init__(self,tagName):
        self.name = tagName
    name1 = 'tagName'
    class cl2:
        name2 = 'name2'

test1 = cl1('test1')
test2 = cl1('test2')
test1.cl2.name2 = "cl1"
test2.cl2.name2 = 'cl2'
print (test1.cl2.name2)
```

When running it, the result is

```
cl2
```

Why it is not "cl1" as assigned?

Comment: You didnt create *any* instances of `cl1.cl2`. You are simply assigning to class variables. Do you think inner classes work like they do in Java? They don't. They are not commonly used in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value:

```
test1.cl2.name2
```

Is a class attribute for the class `cl2`.  It is associated with that class, not with instances of that class.  So even though you're going through references to an instance of the `cl1` class to set the value of that attribute, since there is only one of them, the last thing you set it to wins.  Your `print` statements are printing that same single value.

Google "python class vs instance variables" for a number of good looking write-ups of what the differences are between class and instance variables/attributes.

Here's an example that 1) Provides instance vs class atributes just where it seems you wanted them, and 2) renames the classes involved to have uppercase names so it's obvious when you're referencing an instance attribute vs a class attribute.

```
class Cl1:
    class Cl2:
        def __init__(self, tagName):
            self.name2 = tagName

    def __init__(self, tagName1, tagName2):
        self.name1 = tagName1
        self.cl2 = Cl1.Cl2(tagName2)

test1 = Cl1('test1', 'test2')
test2 = Cl1('test2', 'test2')
test1.cl2.name2 = 'cl1'
test2.cl2.name2 = 'cl2'
print(test1.cl2.name2)
```

Result:

```
cl1
```

Note that because you want to have an instance of the inner class associated with each instance of the outer class, the inner class's constructor has to instantiate an instance of the inner class as part of creating the outer class instance.

Also note the references to `self`.  Instance variables are created inside a classes's constructor (its __init__ function) by referencing them on `self`, a reference to the instance being created.

Comment: Can you please advise on how to modify the code so cl2 can be part of cl1 properties, so that the printout result will be cl1?

Comment: Sure.  I'll say right away that you should always name classes with uppercase first letters and instance and other variables with lowercase.  It makes it a lot easier to see what's going on, and then, you will generally be talking about a class variable when it is on an uppercase name and an instance variable when it is on a lowercase name.

Comment: I hope what I added to the answer gives you the advice you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks. It works pretty well. The key is "self.cl2 = Cl1.Cl2(tagName2)" to defer the inner class to the outer class.

Comment: `Cl1.Cl2` is just the full name of the inner class.  `Cl1.Cl2(tagName2)` creates an instance of that class.  It gets assigned to `self.cl2`, which means that each instance of the `Cl1` class has an instance variable named `cl2` that references an instance of the `Cl2` class.  That's why you can do `test1.cl2.name2`, which is `<Cl1 instance><cl1 attribute pointing to a Cl2 instance><name2 attribute of Cl2 instance>`